# Does an official V5 version of the Tzimisce and Vicissitude exist?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

As a fan of Vampire the Masquerade, my favorite clan is the Tzimisce clan, mostly because I love the Vicissitude Discipline.

I want to put some Tzimisce in my campaign, but I couldn't find anything else than homebrewed things.

Is an official V5 version of Tzimisce and Vicissitude exist?

If not, any info about when a Tzimisce book will be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes.

The [Vampire 5th Edition Companion](https://www.worldofdarkness.com/news/v5-companion-is-available-to-download-now), released on December 16, 2020, has a clan write-up for the Tzimisce, as well as a number of discipline powers to replicate their signature discipline.

Comment: good lord, this necromancy act was mercy!